# i want to compare pointer with the object id how can i achieve it

Tags: android, parse-platform

The doctor id in earning table is referred from user table.it is a pointer field in earning table. how can I get only those records which are of specific doctor? Should I induce the table in it? I have to get only these data which I need to show.

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Earnings");
           query.equalTo("cuurentuserobjetid", "doctorID");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(List<ParseObject> subscriptionList, ParseException e) {

                    }

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Earnings");
           query.equalTo("cuurentuserobjetid", ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User","yourDoctorId"));
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(List<ParseObject> subscriptionList, ParseException e) {

                    }
                }
            });
```